# How to prevent @media query error using materialize and scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, materialize

What am I doing wrong here? The media query is straight from the Materialize Sass docs.

The error I am seeing:

@media #{$medium-and-down} 
Undefined variable: "$medium-and-down"

```
@media #{$medium-and-down} {
  .header-title {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your variable `$medium-and-down` defined anywhere in the Sass?

Comment: No, but its supposed to be a materialize variable, and I'm trying to load it with materialize-loader package.  materialize-loader package says to require("materialize-loader");  To use the complete Materialize package including all styles with the default settings which I have required in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You are probably including the materialize style after your custom sass sheets

Comment: I guess that could be the case, but webpack is doing most of the work here, and I don't know how to change the order it loads.  The materialize-css classes are working, but if I use a color variable, or the screen size I get the variable undefined error.  I changed the order of the webpack config  rules thinking that might work, but it doesnt.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your webpack config and of how you are integrating your bundle in your html/js files?